How to make work CORS for .net core + KeenDNS
I have angular app and .net core API hosted as two separate apps.
I have setup CORS as follows:
        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: _policyName, builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        ...
        app.UseRouting();
        ...

For local network connection using angular app IP address everything is working fine.
I've configured DDNS on my Keenetic (KeenDNS) to forward to my local services:

But when I'm trying to access my app using those url I got CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://tube-api.XXX.keenetic.link/api/account/login' from origin 'https://tube.XXX.keenetic.link' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I've tried to add to policy origins https://tube.XXX.keenetic.link and my router local address - 192.168.1.1 as soon as it works as a reverse proxy. But that also doesn't worked.
I've tryed to set code for allowing origin at runtime and place a breakpoint at this line.
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(url => url.Contains("192.168.1.1")) 

But his breakpoint is hit only when I'm accessing my app by local IP, if I'm using domain name - those code isn't called..
How could I fix that?
